# Seperate scrolling from container

Tags: html, css, scroll, navigation

See this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/fhu2vs39/3/

This is a simplified version of an online magazine I'm making. If you click on the page, it navigates to a new one (in the actual magazine this would be a navigator).

I would like the pages to scroll separately from each other, so that when you scroll down, not the whole container scrolls down but only the current page and when you enter a new page, it's content will be at the top.

I now have

```
.container {
overflow:hidden;
}

.viewer {
overflow-y: auto;
}
```

I tried using overflow-y: auto on the .page, but that doesn't work.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created it, check it out:

> Codepen: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/LYRJOPR

We needed to use `overflow-y: scroll;`

Answer (score 0):

use this on last line of JS: `view.scrollTop = 0;`

see this: https://jsfiddle.net/3farotce/

for animate scrollTop use jQuery library 3.4,

and add this:

```
setTimeout(function () {
        $(view).animate({scrollTop: 0},500)
    },200);
```

see this new fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7fhowp3L/

Comment: Thanks. But I'd actually like a seemless transition. Because there is an easing transition between the left scroll of the pages, the user will see the page going to the top before the the transition takes place. I would like the next page to already be on the top before the sidescrolling takes place.

Comment: @Cas check my new fiddle;